# EOL while concatenating string + path

Tags: python, string, concatenation, eol

I need to concatenate specific folder path with a string, for example:

mystring = "blablabla"
path = "C:\folder\whatever\"

printing (path + mystring) should return:
**C:\folder\whatever\blablabla**

However I always get the EOL error, and it's a must the path to have the slash like this: \ and not like this: /

Please show me the way, I tried with r' it's not working, I tried adding double "", nothing works and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Don't end paths with a backslash. If you use `os.path.join`, you'll never need to anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use escape character `\\` for `\`:

```
mystring = "blablabla"
path = "C:\\folder\\whatever\\"

conc = path + mystring
print(conc)
# C:\folder\whatever\blablabla
```

Or, make use of raw strings, however moving the last backslash from end of `path` to the start of `myString`:

```
mystring = r"\blablabla"
path = r"C:\folder\whatever"

conc = path + mystring
print(conc)
# C:\folder\whatever\blablabla
```

The reason why your own raw string approach didn't work is that a raw strings may not end with a single backslash:

> Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash (since
>   the backslash would escape the following quote character).

From

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Answer (score 2):

Always use `os.path.join()` to join paths and the `r` prefix to allow single back slashes as Windows path separators:

`r"C:\folder\whatever"`

Now, now trailing back slash is needed:

```
>>> import os
>>> mystring = "blablabla"
>>> path = r"C:\folder\whatever"
>>> os.path.join(path, mystring)
'C:\\folder\\whatever\\blablabla'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining !

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, with regards to the EOL error, my best guess - without access to the actual python session - is that python was complaining because you have an unterminated string caused by the final `"` character being escaped, which will happend even if the string is prefixed with `r`. My opinion is that you should drop the prefix and just correctly espace all backslashes like so: `\\`.

In your example, `path`then becomes `path = "C:\\folder\\whatever\\"`

Secondly, instead of manually concatenating paths, you should use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os
mystring = "blablabla"
path = "C:\\folder\\whatever"
print os.path.join(path, mystring)

## prints C:\\folder\\whatever\\blablabla
```

**Note** that `os.path` will use the path convetions for the operating system where the application is running, so the above code will produce erroneous/unexpected results if you run it on, say, Linux. Check the notes on the top of the page that I have linked for details.